# Docker-compose for production running laravel with nginx on azure

Tags: laravel, nginx, docker-compose, production-environment, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have an app that is working but I am getting problems to make it run on Azure.

I have the next docker-compose

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/
      - ./setup/azure/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/template
    environment: 
      PORT: ${PORT}
    command: /bin/sh -c "envsubst '$${PORT}' < /etc/nginx/template/nginx.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
    networks: 
      - mynet 
    depends_on: 
      - app
      - worker

  app:
    image: myimage:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./setup/azure/Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    expose:
      - 9000
    volumes: 
      - uploads:/var/www/simple/public/uploads
      - logos:/var/www/simple/public/logos
    networks:
      - mynet

  worker:
    image: my_image:latest
    command: bash -c "/usr/local/bin/php artisan queue:work --timeout=0"
    depends_on: 
      - app
    networks:
      - mynet

volumes: 
  uploads:
  logos:

networks: 
  mynet:
```

I am unsure if the volumes in nginx ok, I think that perhaps I should create a new Dockerfile to copy the files. However, this would increase a lot the size of the project.

When using App Services on azure the development is made assigning a randomly port, that's wgy i have the envsubst instruction in command. I appreciate any other suggestion to make it run this project on Azure

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to persist the storage in your app to a volume. Check out this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-serve-content-from-azure-storage) [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/55046#issuecomment-630219169). Now I don't think you need

```
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/
      - ./setup/azure/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/template
```

but for

```
    volumes: 
      - uploads:/var/www/simple/public/uploads
      - logos:/var/www/simple/public/logos
```

you can create a storage account, mount it to your linux app plan (it's not available for Windows app plans yet), and mount the relative path `/var/www/simple/public/uploads` to the file path of the storage container.